# Batch processing JMS events in event handling

Tags: callback, event-handling, jms, batch-processing

What is the best practice to process multiple JMS events, possibly arrived as a sequence during a short period of time, say a few milliseconds. For example, my current callback of the event listener's looks like below,

```
    public void onMessage(final Message msg) {
       process(msg);
    }
```

A sequence is usually triggered by a single user action and need to be processed in the same group. I am implementing a PUSH engine of a mobile server, so I can't schedule some command at a fix rate with a long delay. A second or less delay can be tolerated for batch event processing which is also more efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: The only solution I can see is to have a queue holding the incoming JMS messages, and have a scheduler that dequeue it at a rapid pace. Is it very expensive? Seems very noisy.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, with a single thread executor that schedules batch processing of the buffered JMS messages at a fixed pace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tuning, rather than scheduling a periodic bulk processing at a fixed rate, I ended up scheduling one task with a brief delay during the callback. This allows ample time for all related events to arrive into the cache. And once all events in the cache are bulk processed, the cache is cleared, so there is no more to process for the following scheduled tasks (one task scheduled during each callback). The task will resume processing once the cache is filled again.

Of course, the cache need to be made thread safe. I think this approach works the best for my scenario, where short sequences of events arrive in an irregular pace.